# Symfony2 make field entity dynamically

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1

I have a number of fields of an entity that I see on a page, I would like for each of these fields you can edit them via ajax, one at a time.
To do this I came up with the idea of ​​building a unique controller for all fields, but I can not make it work and I do not know if it is the right solution for what I try to do.
my page show field:

```
<div>
 <form class="ajax" action="{{ path('ajax_setSocial', { 'id': entity.id }) }}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>
  <div class="editor">
        {{ form_errors(form) }}
        <div class="editLabel pls lti">{{ form_label(form.ragSocial) }}</div>
        <div class="editField"> 
            <div class="ptm">
                {{ form_widget(form.ragSocial) }} {{ form_errors(form.ragSocial) }}
            </div>     
            {{ form_widget(form._token) }}
            <div class="mtm">
                <button class="btn btn-primary disabled save" type="submit" disabled>Save</button>
                <button class="btn ann">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </div>
  </div>
  </form>
 </div>
 <div>
  <form class="ajax" action="{{ path('ajax_setSocial', { 'id': entity.id }) }}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>
  <div class="editor">
        {{ form_errors(form) }}
        <div class="editLabel pls lti">{{ form_label(form.pIva) }}</div>
        <div class="editField"> 
            <div class="ptm">
                {{ form_widget(form.pIva) }} {{ form_errors(form.pIva) }}
            </div>     
            {{ form_widget(form._token) }}
            <div class="mtm">
                <button class="btn btn-primary disabled save" type="submit" disabled>Save</button>
                <button class="btn ann">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </div>
  </div>
  </form>
 </div>
```

in my controller:

```
public function setSocialAction(Request $request, $id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $entity = $em->getRepository('MyBusinessBundle:Anagrafica')->find($id);

    if (!$entity) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Anagrafic entity.');
    }
    $field = $request->get('field');
    $class = $field.'Type()';
    $form = $this->createForm(new $class, $entity);
    $form->bind($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();

        $response = new Response();
        $output = array('success' => true);
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        $response->setContent(json_encode($output));

        return $response;
    }
```

**$class = $field.'Type()';

$form = $this->createForm(new $class, $entity);**
with these lines of code I try to make dynamic class that generates the form field, but does not work because it is being transformed as a string and the error I get is:

```
Fatal error: Class 'ragSocialType()' not found
```

but the class is! and is also called to the top file ..
I hope I explained, I accept any advice to follow a better way!

Comment: please post your ragSocialType

Comment: It is irrelevant! If I write ragSocialType() directly without having to build name with the variable, it works correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$class = $field.'Type'; //remove the ()
$form = this->createForm(new $class, $entity);
```

Comment: Returns the same error!
To test I put in the variable $class: 
`$class = 'ragSocialeType'; $form = this->createForm(new $class, $entity);  `
Even so, it does not work! Always returns the same error!
I do not understand! In a normal class php it works!

Comment: then use the fully qualified namespace when building the class: like $class= "mybundle\form\" . $field . 'Type';